# App is crashing - cant find reason (Android)

Tags: android, opencv, runtime-error, media-player

I have an android app which seems to be crashing for no reason I cant seem to find the error as in other cases here`s is the log chat

Some more info about the app: It uses opencv libraries , There is a media player there .any suggestions?

**EDIT:** it seems the problem is with the class Mediaplayer cant find it yet though

**EDIT2:** There seems that I put a filter on the error heres the updated log chat

```
                                           java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid format of fabric file,.fabric/
                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:93)
                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:163)
                                               at b.a.a.a.u.c(Onboarding.java:105)
                                               at b.a.a.a.u.f(Onboarding.java:45)
                                               at b.a.a.a.p.a(InitializationTask.java:63)
                                               at b.a.a.a.p.a(InitializationTask.java:28)
                                               at b.a.a.a.a.c.c.call(AsyncTask.java:311)
                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                               at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid format of fabric file,.fabric/
                                               at b.a.a.a.k.a(FabricKitsFinder.java:91)
                                               at b.a.a.a.k.a(FabricKitsFinder.java:58)
                                               at b.a.a.a.k.call(FabricKitsFinder.java:35)
                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                               at com.facebook.interstitial.omnistore.InterstitialConfigurationOmnistoreInit
                                                                             java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null argument: appDefined
                                                                                 at com.facebook.omnistore.CollectionName$Builder.doAddSegment(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.omnistore.CollectionName$Builder.addSegment(CollectionName.java:50)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.interstitial.InterstitialModule.a(InterstitialModule.java:105)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.interstitial.CollectionName_InterstitialConfigurationCollectionMethodAutoProvider.b(CollectionName_InterstitialConfigurationCollectionMethodAutoProvider.java:16)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.interstitial.CollectionName_InterstitialConfigurationCollectionMethodAutoProvider.a(CollectionName_InterstitialConfigurationCollectionMethodAutoProvider.java:84)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.inject.FbInjectorImplHead.i(BindingsTemplate.java:8725)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.inject.FbInjectorImplHead.a(BindingsTemplate.java:36)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.inject.FbInjectorImpl.a(FbInjectorImpl.java:420)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.inject.IdBasedLazy.onGetInstance(IdBasedLazy.java:22)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.inject.AbstractDefaultScopeLazy.get(AbstractDefaultScopeLazy.java:43)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.interstitial.omnistore.InterstitialConfigurationOmnistoreSubscriber.b(InterstitialConfigurationOmnistoreSubscriber.java:125)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.interstitial.omnistore.InterstitialConfigurationOmnistoreInit.init(InterstitialConfigurationOmnistoreInit.java:43)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.common.noncriticalinit.NonCriticalInitializer.a(NonCriticalInitializer.java:103)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.common.noncriticalinit.NonCriticalInitializer$2.run(NonCriticalInitializer.java:116)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.common.appchoreographer.DefaultAppChoreographer$5.run(DefaultAppChoreographer.java:380)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.common.executors.WrappingExecutorService$1.run(WrappingExecutorService.java:77)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.common.executors.DefaultConstrainedListeningExecutorService$Worker.run(DefaultConstrainedListeningExecutorService.java:327)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                 at com.facebook.common.executors.NamedThreadFactory$1.run(NamedThreadFactory.java:42)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-08 11:30:39.131 313-698/? E/Vold: Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.facebook.pages.app/files/
04-08 11:30:39.141 313-698/? E/Vold: Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/extSdCard/Android/data/com.facebook.pages.app/files/
04-08 11:31:00.281 30651-30651/? E/accuweather: [KK AccuPhone]>>> UIM:1501 [0:0] bTM 11 31
04-08 11:31:07.301 1073-1534/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 701 [04-08 11:31:07.314]
04-08 11:31:20.501 1073-1189/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
04-08 11:31:20.501 1073-1189/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
04-08 11:31:20.501 1073-1189/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
04-08 11:31:20.501 1073-1189/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
04-08 11:31:20.541 18093-18093/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
04-08 11:31:20.551 18093-18093/? E/Zygote: v2
04-08 11:31:20.561 18093-18093/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-08 11:31:20.561 18093-18093/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: platform sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
04-08 11:31:20.911 18093-18093/? E/TranscodeReceiver: onReceive : android.intent.action.CHECK_SIOP_LEVEL
04-08 11:31:24.811 17126-17126/? E/MtpServerJNI: server is null in send_object_removed
04-08 11:31:24.821 2225-2225/? E/ctxmgr: [PowerConnectionProducer]Could not write powerInfo=Plug state: 2 BatteryLevel: 0.86, status=Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 7503, resolution=null}
04-08 11:31:30.961 1073-1366/? E/EnterpriseSharedDevicePolicy: isSharedDeviceEnabled
04-08 11:31:30.961 1073-1196/? E/PowerManagerService: handleSandman : startDreaming, but isDreaming false
04-08 11:31:31.351 1073-1293/? E/SmartFaceService: onReceive: android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
04-08 11:31:31.371 1073-1293/? E/SmartFaceService: fail to set sysfs 0
04-08 11:31:31.441 1073-1305/? E/MotionRecognitionService:  handler : SCREEN_OFF end 
04-08 11:31:31.441 1073-1189/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
04-08 11:31:31.441 1073-1189/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
04-08 11:31:31.441 1073-1189/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
04-08 11:31:31.441 1073-1189/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
04-08 11:31:31.451 18271-18271/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
04-08 11:31:31.451 18271-18271/? E/Zygote: v2
04-08 11:31:31.461 18271-18271/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-08 11:31:31.461 18271-18271/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: platform sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
04-08 11:31:31.521 1073-1187/? E/Sensors: RED : 1129, GREEN : 809, BLUE : 788, CLEAR : 1503,Lux = 131.000000, CCT = 2784.000000, RawLux = 131.000000
04-08 11:31:31.531 1073-1337/? E/WifiNative-wlan0: do suspend true
04-08 11:31:31.591 1073-1073/? E/SContext.CaeProvider: setAttribute() : attribute is null!
04-08 11:31:31.881 1073-1187/? E/Sensors: RED : 1133, GREEN : 811, BLUE : 789, CLEAR : 1510,Lux = 132.000000, CCT = 2782.000000, RawLux = 132.000000
04-08 11:31:32.021 2277-2277/? E/LibSecureUISvc: svc_sock_send_message(suisvc): Error sending data, -1 vs 4: Connection refused
04-08 11:31:32.501 1073-1187/? E/Sensors: Sensor : Meta event
04-08 11:31:32.781 18271-18271/? E/SQLiteLog: (283) recovered 10 frames from WAL file /data/data/com.android.settings/databases/mysettings.db-wal
04-08 11:31:35.411 1073-2307/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
04-08 11:31:35.411 1073-2307/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
04-08 11:31:35.411 1073-2307/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
04-08 11:31:35.411 1073-2307/? E/ActivityManager: checkUser: useridlist=null, currentuser=0
04-08 11:31:35.441 18368-18368/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
04-08 11:31:35.441 18368-18368/? E/Zygote: v2
04-08 11:31:35.451 18368-18368/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-08 11:31:35.451 18368-18368/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
04-08 11:31:36.111 1401-1401/? E/EnterpriseSharedDevicePolicy: isSharedDeviceEnabled
04-08 11:31:36.121 1401-1401/? E/KeyguardViewMediator: setShowingLocked mShowing true
04-08 11:31:36.201 18368-18368/com.aar.Cline E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
04-08 11:31:36.291 1401-1401/? E/LSO: LSO Service is not yet ready!!!
04-08 11:31:36.321 339-339/? E/SEC_DRM_PLUGIN_Omafl: OmaPlugin::onOpenDecryptSession(fd)::Drm2IsDrmFileByExtFd::file is NOT DRM by extension
04-08 11:31:36.341 18368-18368/com.aar.Cline E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
04-08 11:31:36.391 1073-1073/? E/EnterpriseSharedDevicePolicy: isSharedDeviceEnabled
04-08 11:31:36.401 18368-18368/com.aar.Cline E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
04-08 11:31:36.921 340-18428/? E/ACodec: onConfigureComponent mime.c_str() = audio/vorbis
04-08 11:31:37.071 340-18435/? E/ACodec: onConfigureComponent mime.c_str() = audio/vorbis
04-08 11:31:37.181 1073-1293/? E/SmartFaceService: onReceive: android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
04-08 11:31:37.181 1073-1293/? E/SmartFaceService: mFolderCoverOpened: (true, true) -> true
04-08 11:31:37.281 18368-18368/com.aar.Cline E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
04-08 11:31:37.301 1073-1534/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 702 [04-08 11:31:37.319]
04-08 11:31:37.331 2043-2043/? E/InputEventModelImpl: onStartInput event aborted: com.touchtype.keyboard.c.ae: could not obtain extracted text (class com.touchtype.keyboard.c.ae)
04-08 11:31:37.341 339-339/? E/SEC_DRM_PLUGIN_Omafl: OmaPlugin::onOpenDecryptSession(fd)::Drm2IsDrmFileByExtFd::file is NOT DRM by extension
04-08 11:31:37.341 18368-18368/com.aar.Cline E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
04-08 11:31:37.361 18368-18368/com.aar.Cline E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
01-01 00:00:00.000 0-0/? E/Internal: device '455a6521' not found
```

**Media Recorder Initialization :**

```
  private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.settingsBtn)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.matchBallBtn)).setOnClickListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.champions_league);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        CircleButton b2 = (CircleButton) findViewById(R.id.trackBallBtn);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        if(mMediaPlayer!=null && PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("backgroundMusic", true))
            mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

Comment: there must be another logcat crash report with the exact hint to the error...maybe you haven´t set the filter propably..

Comment: You are right and edit is coming

Comment: could you please post the part where you are initializing your media recorder?

Comment: yes please look at it @Opiatefuchs

Comment: does it crash every time? I mean, does it work for example on the first start but later not? In your code I can´t see any wrong implementation. Can you figure out the line where it´s crashing?

Comment: there must be something wrong in Your FabricKitsFinder class at line 91

Comment: have You generated a custom file with .fabric extension?

Comment: What is FabricKitsFinder , I dont remember using it @Opiatefuchs

Comment: Sorry, FabricKitsFinder seems to be a  part of third party sdk. the only thing I can imagine that the media player is not ready for playing if you call so. you can set a onPreparedListener and start the player if it is prepared...in the meanwhile I am looking for FabricKitsFinder...want to know what it is....

Comment: can you show me your import declarations of this class where it crashs?

Comment: are you using Crashlytics? And it seems You are using facebook sdk, maybe anywhere in that two cases is the problem...